# script no longer updating the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html page which displays a picture at a random location and updates it every 10 seconds :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Domoos | Screen saver screen</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_saver.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
    var xmin = 0;
    var xmax = 890;
    var ymin = 0;
    var ymax = 430;
    var xCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*xmax)+xmin);
    var yCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*ymax)+ymin);
    var xCoordStr = xCoord.toString() + "px";
    var yCoordStr = yCoord.toString() + "px";
    document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.left = xCoordStr;
    document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.top = yCoordStr;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<div style="position:absolute" id="randomPlacement">
<p><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/pictures/texte_sortie_veille.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works very well. Now, I would like to add two 'div' tags so I could display the date and the time. So, I updated the body tag as follows (the rest of the page remains unchanged) :

```
<body onload="init();">
 <div style="position:absolute" id="randomPlacement">
 <p><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/pictures/texte_sortie_veille.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></a></p>
</div>
<div id="date">
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getDate('date');</script>
</div>
<div id="time">
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getTime('time');</script>
</div>
</body>
```

The problem by doing so is that the image is never displayed at a random location. What am I missing and hopefully how can I solve the issue? I have added an extract of the console in Chrome.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console?

Comment: What should I look at?

Comment: On Chrome right click on the page and select Inspect. Then go to the second tab (named "Console") in the window that opens. On Firefox it's Inspect Element > Console. It'll show the JavaScript errors on your page.

Comment: You are calling window.onload which is event for entire window.so the                 onload="init();" not working at right time. I think you should call getdate() and gettime() in init()

Comment: Thanks, Kabir Roy, I have followed your instruction. But the log file seems to be empty. Can it be possible?

Comment: ' function init() {
    var xmin = 0;
    var xmax = 890;
    var ymin = 0;
    var ymax = 430;
    var xCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*xmax)+xmin);
    var yCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*ymax)+ymin);
    var xCoordStr = xCoord.toString() + "px";
    var yCoordStr = yCoord.toString() + "px";
    document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.left = xCoordStr;
    document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.top = yCoordStr; /////may be here
}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
  <div id="date">
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getDate('date');</script>
</div>
<div id="time">
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getTime('time');</script>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="time">

</div>
```

then in init()

```
 function init() {
        var xmin = 0;
        var xmax = 890;
        var ymin = 0;
        var ymax = 430;
        var xCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*xmax)+xmin);
        var yCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*ymax)+ymin);
        var xCoordStr = xCoord.toString() + "px";
        var yCoordStr = yCoord.toString() + "px";
        document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.left = xCoordStr;
        document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.top = yCoordStr;
        document.getElementById("date").innerhtml=getDate('date');
document.getElementById("time").innerhtml=gettime('time');
    }
```

Comment: Perfect. One thousand thanks for your quick help. Best wishes